# changing HTML jumpmenu into PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Here is the code I have in HTML:

```
<FORM NAME="jumpform">
<SELECT NAME="pages" onChange = "window.status = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE="tutorial_part1.html">1 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part2.html">2 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part3.html">3 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part7_frames.html">4 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part8.html">5 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part9.html">6 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part10_frames.html">7 of 7
</SELECT>
<INPUT VALUE="Go" TYPE=BUTTON onClick = "jump (document.jumpform.pages.options[pages.selectedIndex].value)">
</FORM>
```

When I use PHP to add a header and a footer to the page, the jump menu doesn't work. the options change when you select them, but nothing happens when you click "Go". How can I rewrite this so that when I add php code to the page, and when I change the file extensions to .php, the jumpform still works?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use caps in your HTML - it looks horrid :-(

Comment: I never do... I'm modifying someone else's code.

Comment: Ah my bad. Good to know one out of two has good practises :-)

Answer (score 0):

close php tags before form, and after the form for example

```
<?php //php code
?>
<FORM NAME="jumpform">
<SELECT NAME="pages" onChange = "window.status = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE="tutorial_part1.html">1 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part2.html">2 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part3.html">3 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part7_frames.html">4 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part8.html">5 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part9.html">6 of 7
<OPTION VALUE="tutorial_part10_frames.html">7 of 7
</SELECT>
<INPUT VALUE="Go" TYPE=BUTTON onClick = "jump (document.jumpform.pages.options[pages.selectedIndex].value)">
</FORM>
<?php //other php code 
?>
```

that should be it.

Comment: the new page looks something like this:<?php include('header.php');?> Body content including form <?php include('footer.php');?> The header and footer provide the html and body tags. All I'm doing is plugging in the content from the original page. On the original, the form "goes". On the page generated by php, the form does not "go".